# What is the Joomla Execution Flow, after a request reach to index.php till the final output on the browser?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-api, cms, joomla-3.5

Based on this question: **[How Templates work and load css/js files? Website building process with Purity III](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17095/website-building-process-of-purity-iii/)**

> **Quote:**
>   .... I have to present my website tomorrow and i may get asked "where does
>   the content come from?" and i can't answer because i don't get it
>   myself.
>
> What does happen if I call the site? In the index.php file is php code
>   but i can't find the spot where the rest of the website gets "called"
>   or something....

and also on type of questions like this: **[Where Joomla Files Located](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17106/where-joomla-files-located)**

I decided to create this Q/A to work as a reference for all similar questions. Anyone who would like to contribute to make this a solid community wiki post is welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **Answer's ToC**
>   1. Intro for beginners + beginners resources link
>   2. About Joomla Architecture
>   3. Joomla Execution Flow - How Joomla Works
>   4. Supplementary Resources

## 1. Intro for Beginners

Using Joomla for site building is rather simple, as it provides a friendly administration area. In most cases this is all that is needed to know for end-users and designers.

A lot of beginners with some knowledge on classic static html and css, have this same common question/expectation: How to edit their files/content, as they see it being rendered on their browser.

However **the way Joomla works behind the scenes, is a lot more complicated** than editing an html file and requires advanced programming knowledge and experience to fully understand it.

So as a short answer: don't expect to open the **FTP/File manager app** and find a file called : `myArticle.html`, or `index.html` that will let you edit it directly or change the appearance of the html elements of your page.

To start, I would suggest to learn first the **basics of Joomla** and how to manage it from the backend. Slowly, slowly more knowledge and experienced will be gained.

### Beginners resources

A topic with helpful resources and tutorials can be found here:
**[Joomla Beginner Tutorials - How to start with Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/joomla-beginner-tutorials-how-to-start-with-joomla/)**

---

## 2. About Joomla Architecture

**Joomla** is more than a **modern CMS** built on PHP. It's an advanced web project incorporating multi-layers architecture, that includes:

- The **Joomla framework** -including 3rd party libraries that the framework relies on, and the plugins that extend the framework.
- **Separate Web Applications** like the administrator site, the front-end site, the installation.
- **The extensions layer** (modules, components, templates) that extend the Joomla framework and the applications.

Joomla implements various advanced programming concepts, **Object Oriented Programming**, **MVC design pattern** and other common design patterns, a **template system** etc. Also to not forget to mention that Joomla makes use of a **database** where data are saved and retrieved when requested to be displayed on screen.

---

## 3. Simple and Brief Description of Joomla's Execution Cycle - How Joomla Works

When you reach at the **`index.php`** of the a Joomla site (the front-end JSite application), a whole new **execution cycle** starts, that includes:

- Important includes of files that define the application's **CONSTANTS** that are used widely across the application and its extensions.
- Loading the **Joomla framework** and all its essential **Classes** that are required for the application to work down the road, -the framework also checks if there is a **configuration file** in place, or it should take us to the installation folder for making a new Joomla installation.
- The **[Application](https://docs.joomla.org/Category:Application) object** is created and initialised and the session state is handled (new or existing session).
- The **configuration** file is loaded - that gives also access to the database.
- The **[router](https://docs.joomla.org/Routing_implementation_details)** is called. The router is responsible for translating **URLs** to an **associative array of commands** and vice versa. These commands will be used as url parameters and sent to **PHP's `$_GET` SuperGlobal** to make up a complete url. The `option` element of this array is the one that defines the component that should be executed.
- With the execution of the component, the **[Document Object](https://docs.joomla.org/Category:JDocument)** is created. Document is stored in memory and holds data that will be returned later on the browser. The fact that is stored as buffer in memory allows to put and manipulate content in it at no particular order and from any locations. The selected **template** has been stored in the configuration. Also, it worths noting that the only thing Joomla is doing is to run the component. What else should happen during this step is the job of the component.
- Next comes the **Page's Rendering**, where alongside the component data from previous step, modules and notification messages are also rendered and placed in their template positions.
- Final step is to **output the page to the browser**.
- **Important to note** that during various stages of the above execution cycle, there are **[Plugin Events](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events)** points that are called, which allow the various events to interfere and extend Joomla functionality.

A more detailed execution flow list, with the plugin events is documented here: **[Joomla Application Execution Flow](https://docs.joomla.org/Application_execution_order)**

---

## 4. Supplementary Resources:

- **[Joomla Application Execution Flow](https://docs.joomla.org/Application_execution_order)**
- **[Component Program Flow](https://docs.joomla.org/Component_Program_Flow)**
- **[Joomla Architecture](https://docs.joomla.org/Archived:CMS_Architecture_in_1.5_and_1.6)**
- **[Basics of Joomla Components](https://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions)**
- **[Developing a MVC Component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Introduction)**
- **[Joomla 3.x extension development tutorial for a beginner developer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer)**
- **[What tools can I use to help assist me with Joomla development?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/what-tools-can-i-use-to-help-assist-me-with-joomla-development)**

Answer (score 1):

Small contribution, the full list of **[Joomla! Plugin Events](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events)**.

Comment: small but useful

Comment: maybe you could write the most essential parts of that page here

Comment: @FFrewin I would but basically it's a long list of links of each Plugin events! I'm trying to find a sort of "timeline" of all the events in this list but I can't find much about it, I've stumbled in your answer here after lot of googling and the [Joomla Application Execution Flow](https://docs.joomla.org/Application_execution_order) do mention some of the System group Events but not much about all others.

Comment: @FFrewin also would be useful a sort of overview description of all different *groups* of plugin events, but I didn't find much in the Joomla docs (tho I admit my GoogleFu is a bit lacking these days dunno why, maybe is the heat :P)